# Deparse statements of custom function in R

Tags: r, function

I have the following simple custom function:

```r
a_function = function(x) {x + 1}
a_function
#> function(x) {x + 1}
```

I would like to only `deparse` the statement part of a custom function. So in this case it should only return `'x + 1'`. But when I try to use `deparse` on the function it of course takes the complete input like this:

```r
a_function = function(x) {x + 1}
a_function
#> function(x) {x + 1}
deparse(a_function)
#> [1] "function (x) " "{"             "    x + 1"     "}"
cat(deparse(a_function))
#> function (x)  {     x + 1 }
```

As you can see it returns the complete function, but I would like to have this as desired output:

```r
#> x + 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So I was wondering if anyone knows a way to deparse the statements of a custom function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `body` to only get the function body. This also returns the curly brackets so to remove them (and some whitespace) you can use e.g. this:

```r
deparse_body <- function(f) {
  f <- trimws(deparse(body(f)))
  if (f[1] == '{') f <- head(f[-1], -1)
  f
}
deparse_body(a_function)
# [1] "x + 1"
```

Comment: Good call on the `body()` but careful with chopping off parts using indices - if a short function is defined without curly brackets, e.g. `minus  <- \(x) -x
`, this will return `character(0)`.

Comment: @SamR You're absolutely right, thanks! I updated the answer so now it should work fine.

Comment: Nice one. Interestingly, as R is a bizarre language with very few rules it is still technically possible to circumvent your logic - curly braces in functions can be wrapped in parentheses as well, e.g. `f  <- \(x) ({y <- x^2; y-x})`. But I don't think I've ever actually seen anyone do this.

Comment: I am afraid there is an infinite number of creative ways function body can be wrapped in brackets or parantheses, e.g. `\(x) {{{{{{{{x}}}}}}}}` :) But yes, it is something one should be aware of.

Comment: The curly brackets are *part* of the function body.  Removing them changes it.  `{ x + 1 }` is really a function call to the `{` function, with argument `x + 1`.  Yes, R is a bizarre language.